# BigQuery for GitHub : How to get most starred repo with a specific language

Tags: github, google-bigquery

I want to get the list of the repo with the most amount stars using BigQuery. I wrote a query but I am not sure about the result :

```
SELECT
  repo.name, 
  count(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, '$.pull_request.base.repo.stargazers_count')) as Stars
FROM `githubarchive.year.2019`  
WHERE
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, '$.pull_request.base.repo.language') = 'Java'
GROUP by repo.name
ORDER BY
  count(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, '$.pull_request.base.repo.stargazers_count')) DESC
LIMIT
  100
```

Can anyone check this with me while adding a new column with the repo url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good start - but note that you have a query that goes over 1TB of data, and will quickly consume your monthly free quota.

I'll recommend you to start by extracting all the interesting rows (like the Java related ones) to a new table. Then run your future queries out of the smaller table.

This query will give you the results you want:

```sql
SELECT repo.name
  , MAX(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, '$.pull_request.base.repo.stargazers_count')AS INT64)) stars
FROM `githubarchive.month.201912`  
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, '$.pull_request.base.repo.language') = 'Java'
AND type='PullRequestEvent'
GROUP by repo.name
ORDER BY stars DESC
```

[image]

- I'm only looking at repos that had pull requests during December 2019. It might be a good sign of the repo being alive.
- Since I'm only looking at December, the query cost is 1/12th.
- `MAX()` gives you the total count of stars at the moment of the pull request.

Now let me create and share with you a way smaller table, to get the top starred repositories by language:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `fh-bigquery.github_extracts.201912_repo_lang_stars`
AS
  SELECT repo.name
    , MAX(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, '$.pull_request.base.repo.stargazers_count')AS INT64)) stars
    , JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, '$.pull_request.base.repo.language') lang
  FROM `githubarchive.month.201912`  
  WHERE type='PullRequestEvent'
  GROUP by repo.name, lang
  # 28.1 sec elapsed, 161.7 GB processed
;

SELECT lang
  , COUNT(*) repos
  , ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(name, stars) ORDER BY stars DESC LIMIT 3) repo
FROM `fh-bigquery.github_extracts.201912_repo_lang_stars`
GROUP BY lang
ORDER BY repos DESC 
# 1.4 sec elapsed, 52.2 MB processed
```

[image]

[image]

- https://twitter.com/felipehoffa/status/1220470249310445572